# Need help adapting a Python 3.x script to run under Python 2.7 (urllib.request & urllib.parse)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I need assistance to adapt a Python 3.x script using (urllib.request and urlllib.parse modules) to run in a old Python 2.7 environment.  I have no experience with Python 2.7 (and the older urllib module).  I am hoping someone would kindly show me how to modify the below script (with the least amount of modification) in order for me to understand the differences.

```Python
import random
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import re
import webbrowser

if eg.globals.bb_cmd.startswith('Play'):
        title = eg.globals.bb_cmd.replace('Play ', '')
        query_string = urllib.parse.urlencode({"search_query": title})
        html_content = urllib.request.urlopen(
            "http://www.youtube.com/results?" + query_string)
        search_results = re.findall(
            r'href=\"\/watch\?v=(.{11})', html_content.read().decode())
        URL = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + search_results[0]
        webbrowser.open(URL)
        ReturnMsg = 'Now playing ' + title
        EndSession = 'yes'
```

Comment: Why would a script that does nothing but scrape YouTube URLs and open the first one need to run in a Python 2 environment? Wouldn't you be better off just moving over to Python 3? I can see needing 2 in a large commercial or academic setting, but in this case it's more than a little odd. If you *must* it's the lines starting with `query_string = ` up to and including `.decode())` you'll need to rewrite - the rest is the same. I'd recommend getting `requests` for Python 2, it'd be pretty similar. Still think it's probably a bad idea though.

Comment: It's not under my control which Python version to use.  I found the YouTube script made for Python 3.  I'm still new to Python. I would appreciate a real Stackoverflow answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to convert this script to Python 2 compatible using requests module (per suggestion in the comments.  It was the simplest way to achieve what I needed.

```python
import random
import requests
import re
import webbrowser

    elif   eg.globals.bb_cmd.startswith('Play'):
                    title = eg.globals.bb_cmd.replace('Play ', '')
                    html_content = requests.get('https://www.youtube.com/results?', params={'search_query': title})
                    search_results = re.findall(r'href=\"\/watch\?v=(.{11})', html_content.text)
                    URL = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + search_results[0]
                    webbrowser.open(URL)
                    ReturnMsg = 'Now playing ' + title
                    EndSession = 'yes'
```